# Custom Google Calendar Add Event form

Tags: google-calendar-api

Is it possible to change the google calendars default add event pop-up with a webapp? I have a form setup as a stand alone and when I get it working it just has a bunch of form fields that it puts together into the title and decription.

Is it possable to call that form from inside the calendar app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can override the default pop-up, unless you build a browser extension, which is not compatible with your requirement to do it with a webapp.

Comment: Would it be possible to call that function from inside the calendar like in Spreadsheet?

Comment: I don't think so. A lot of UI Services offered by Google Spreadsheets are only available from Google Spreadsheets unfortunately.

Comment: Anyone know of an existing Chrome extension that might be close to what I am looking for? I have never built one before so it will be a new experience.

Comment: I don't, but you should not be worried about it. If you can write Google Apps Script code, you've got all the skills required to build Chrome Extensions. It's actually pretty straightforward.

Comment: I marked it answred, I dont have enough Reputation to up vote yet. But I wont forget when I have enough